# Weird php hyperlink issue

Tags: php, html, css

This is kinda tricky as I'm using php to output my content and it's a lot of code.

If you go to http://www.nunchycrut.com#nav=resources&rsc=articles&year=2014 you should see articles listed for 2014 - there is only one called memory lane.

When you mouseover the link it doesn't seem to work as it should. the link is underlined on a mouseover but it seems you have to click the actual horizontal underline to follow the link, if you click on the text it won't work.

All of the other links (in orange) on the page are created using the same class this only appears to be happening in the article listings.

Here's the section of php that is outputting the article link:

```
<div
    style='position: relative; float: left; margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 4px;'
    onclick='showArticle(\"" . $strY ."\", \"" . $arrLines[4] . "\");'
>
        <b>" . $arrLines[1] . " -- </b>
        <a
            href='#nav=resources&rsc=articles&year=" . $strY . "&art=" . $arrLines[4] . "'
        >
            " . $arrLines[0] . "
        </a>
</div>
```

$arrLines[0] holds the actual article name (memorylane). I've been playing about with this for a while trying to figure it out, it's the fact that other links are working fine. I've never seen this before with a hyperlink, anyone any clues?

I can post the css class code but I don't think that's the issue here as like I said, the class is being used all over without problems (the 2014 and 2015 article archive links for example).

It's not a huge problem on a browser but I tested it with my phone and it's quite difficult to open that particular link due to this issue/

I did try using the onclick='' attribute in the actual hyperlink like:

```
        <a
            href='#nav=resources&rsc=articles&year=" . $strY . "&art=" . $arrLines[4] . "'
            onclick='showArticle(\"" . $strY ."\", \"" . $arrLines[4] . "\");'
        >
            " . $arrLines[0] . "
        </a>
```

But it's still doing the same thing. Happening in all browsers, any ideas or solutions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: this wouldn't be a problem if you actually had a `showArticle` function

Comment: I have the showArticle() function, it's a javascript function and I know that isn't the problem as it's being called from elsewhere.

Comment: Well if you do, it's not being loaded. And if it was you wouldn't need anything in your href and anywhere you clicked on that title would actually show the article.

Comment: I tried a few of the solutions offered here - it's a weird one for sure but appreciate the input. Much obliged.

Comment: It is being loaded if you click the link on the underline part, that's the problem. The href part is simply being used to build a link/reference to the particular page. I think I'll redesign the page to be honest. I think this particular problem most likely stems from an error elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, that's only if you click the underline, because your `showArticle` function is not working. digging deeper it looks like that script is coming from `articles.php` which has a body tag inside of another body tag. You should really rethink your design approach. Looks like all your included pages have their own set of `<body></body>`.

Comment: Opps, you're right I did leave body tags in those pages. Thanks for pointing that out and for taking time to help, most grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make 2 changes (remove float:left):

```
<p class="ContentReg" style="position: relative; margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 4px;" onclick="showArticle(&quot;2014&quot;, &quot;memorylane&quot;);">
                        <b>November 12, 2014
 -- </b>
                        <a href="#nav=resources&amp;rsc=articles&amp;year=2014&amp;art=memorylane">
                            A trip down memory lane.

                        </a>
                    </p>
```

and change (remove position:relative)

```
<p class="ContentSmall" style="float: right; margin-top: 8px; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 4px; text-align: right;">
                        By <font color="#6495ED">Nunchy
</font>
                    </p>
```

Comment: gee someone is busy down voting the people who have addressed the OP issue. Shows what little the down voter knows.

Comment: This solved the issue, thanks muchly it's most appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Remove `position: relative` in your inline style for paragraph tag.

```js
<p class="ContentSmall" style="/* position: relative; */ float: top; margin-top: 8px; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 4px; text-align: right;">
```

Comment: So whoever down voted this, why exactly is this not correct? This solution directly resolved the issue of the link not being clickable and that being the only issue requested in this post. Please elaborate.

Answer (score -3):

Your hyperlink needs to go from:

```
href='#nav=resources&rsc=articles&year=" . $strY . "&art=" . $arrLines[4] . "'
```

to:

```
href='#?nav=resources&rsc=articles&year=$strY&art=$arrLines[4]'
```

When you use a double quote (") with an echo it will echo the variable, however if you use a single quote (') with an echo it will echo the text as is.

When constructing a hyperlink for PHP you should keep in mind:

## - where on the page to go

? - indicates you're setting page variables